# If statement inside echoed html not showing inside the html

Tags: php, html

I want to shorten a string when it's longer than a certain length for example 20.

But when I add the if statement to my echoed html it outputs the result outside of the echoed html. Any idea why this happens?

My code:

```
    foreach($contentcr as $content) 
    {
        $contentje .= '<li class="job_listing">
        <a href="http://www.website.nl/_extern/website/content.php?alias='.$content['alias'].'">
            <div class="location job_img">
                <img src="images/samples/person1.jpg" alt="" class="company_logo">
            </div>
            <div class="location boldfont">
                '.$content['title'].'
            </div>
            <div class="location">
            '.$content['fulltext'].'';
            if (strlen($content['fulltext']) >= 20){
                    echo 'blala';
                }

            $contentje .='</div>
            <div class="rating location">
                <div class="rating-stars">
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="location">


    '.$content['metakey'].'
        </div>
        <div class="location">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary buttonblock" onClick="location.href="http://www.website.nl/_extern/website/content.php?page="'.$content['alias'].'">Nu huren</button>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>'; // Here
}
```

This is a table like structure, but the output of the if statement is echoed outside the html markup.

Comment: concat to  $contentje instead of  echo 'blala'

Comment: Thanks! that did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **echoing** the **string inside if statement** rather than appending that to your `$contentje` variable. See if statement below:

```
foreach($contentcr as $content) 
{
    $contentje .= '<li class="job_listing">
    <a href="http://www.website.nl/_extern/website/content.php?alias='.$content['alias'].'">
        <div class="location job_img">
            <img src="images/samples/person1.jpg" alt="" class="company_logo">
        </div>
        <div class="location boldfont">
            '.$content['title'].'
        </div>
        <div class="location">
        '.$content['fulltext'].'';
        if (strlen($content['fulltext']) >= 20){
            $contentje .= 'blala';
        }

        $contentje .='</div>
        <div class="rating location">
            <div class="rating-stars">
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="location"> '.$content['metakey'].'</div>
        <div class="location">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary buttonblock" onClick="location.href="http://www.website.nl/_extern/website/content.php?page="'.$content['alias'].'">Nu huren</button>
        </div>
    </a></li>'; // Here
}
```